# Download an APK which is uploaded in Alpha version play store

Tags: android, google-play

My app is already published.Now I wish to update it with newer version,But I did some serious changes so I wish to check it first in alpha version.
I uploaded my apk with next version in alpha,It is completely 24 hours,But still now It is not showing in playstore,In playstore my old app version is present.
I have logged in with tester-id which I have added to google-group(tester).

I am not trying to download old apk,
But trying to download the apk which I have uploaded in alpha testing.
the app which is in production have version 6.
and I uploaded version 7 in alpha testing.when I am opening the tester link with tester id,I expect it should show me my app with latest version(ie. version 7).
But still it showing version 6.

Can any one tell me how do I download it,As I am not able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, you cant find your app using search box, you can use generated direct link only.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775522/4183017)

Comment: :-
I think you didnt get my question.plz check updated question

Comment: Is your old application seen on google play? And you wish to update it with newer version that is uploaded as alpha?

Comment: yes it is in google play store with version 6.
now I uploaded version 7 in alpha testing.
no I dont want to take it in production.

Comment: Can you find your alpha version on console?

Comment: according to google document,If I am tester,then I should able to view it in google play.But I am not able to see it,the tester link open app with version 6.

Comment: thanks Ioane Sharvadze,
But I am using the generated direct link only.
but still it is not showing updates version.
I got that auto generated link in alpha testing section.

Comment: no it is not showing 404
It is showing old version which is in production.

Comment: It is showing old version which is in production. 
not new version which I have uploaded in alpha testing

Comment: Check your apk, maybe you uploaded old version.

Comment: no thats not the problem,I have checked in developer console it shows new version in alpha .and previous version in production.