# Can I publish private apps on the Play Store without G Suite?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish a private app on the Play Store for only my customers to use. Is that possible without having G suite?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you can publish the app in Alpha/ Closed Beta channel where only the people you have added to the group can see and install the app.

Refer the [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for more info:

> Closed beta: Consider closed beta testing if you want to run a test
>   with a smaller group (like within your company or team) or when you
>   know the exact users you want to test your app. If you're testing an
>   existing app that you've published before, only users in your test
>   group will receive an update for your alpha/beta version.

Comment: Ok, would ANYONE be able to see the app but not be able to get it? I don't want this app to be seen by anyone but my customers, even if they can't install it

Comment: I suppose it is. From this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16775522/4586742 "normal" uses will not find your app on Google Play, but also the activated tester can not find the application by using the search box.

Comment: Or instead of Play store, you can even distribute using other tools, like Fabric Beta:  http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/