# Cannot open Opt-in URL in google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I released an app as alpha version [I have never used alpha release before] in google play. I added 3 testers and sent Opt-in URL to testers. But when they click that link on their android device the following message box appear and can't do anything. How can they become testers for my app? What the problem is?[image: ]]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659204/where-do-alpha-testers-download-google-play-android-apps?rq=1

Check whether it helps

Comment: Do they have a browser installed?

Comment: @KNeerajLal Yes they have. They are using google chrome.

Comment: It's actually opening the app in google play because of the play.* url there must a bug in the play store that doesn't find the web browser on your phone. I am getting this issue with alpha testing too

Comment: For your info the fix to this bug should now be fully rolled out to everyone on the latest version of the Play store app

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see this is a bug with the play store.

It is opening the app and when the going to play.google* and then trying to  then open up your web browser and for some reason it can't find the web browser.

I have tested using a tinyurl as well and that has not changed the result

I suggest until google fixes the issue, get your testers to hold on the link in the email you send them and choose to open with web browser rather than just clicking it. You could also try out some other mobile testing apps eg https://fabric.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Play Store. The fix should be rolling out soon. In the meantime, there are a few workarounds:

1. You can always open this URL on your Laptop/Desktop.
2. You can manually copy OPT-IN URL to the new browser tab.
3. Go into the System App Settings for the Play Store, "Open by default" -> "Open supported links" -> "Ask every time".

Comment: why - ? this is actually what is going on